ASP.NET 8 Windows Authentication combined with custom policy authorization results in HandleRequirementAsync() being called twice for every request
I created a new "ASP.NET Core Web API" project.
In Program.cs I configured authentication and authorization as follows:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, CanGetWeatherAuthorizationHandler>();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
  options.AddPolicy("CanGetWeather", policy =>
    policy.Requirements.Add(new CanGetWeatherRequirement()));
});

I don't think they are relevant to the issue, but here is CanGetWeatherRequirement.cs:
public class CanGetWeatherRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}

and CanGetWeatherAuthorizationHandler.cs:
public class CanGetWeatherAuthorizationHandler() : AuthorizationHandler<CanGetWeatherRequirement>
{
  protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(
    AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
    CanGetWeatherRequirement requirement
  )
  {
    var userId = context.User.Identities.First();

    if (userId.IsAuthenticated)
    {
      if (await UserCanGetWeatherAsync())
        context.Succeed(requirement);
    }
  }

  private static async Task<bool> UserCanGetWeatherAsync() =>
    await Task.Run(() => Random.Shared.NextDouble() > 0.5);
}

I expected, when sending a GET request to the WeatherForecast endpoint, that the  HandleRequirementAsync method will be called once with the context containing an authenticated user ID (context.User.Identities.First().IsAuthenticated == true).
Instead it is being called twice

The first time context.User.Identities.First().IsAuthenticated is false
The second time context.User.Identities.First().IsAuthenticated is true


Windows Authentication can run on Kestrel or IIS Express.

If you run on IIS Express, it will call HandleRequirementAsync once. Be sure the properties(windowsAuthentication and anonymousAuthentication) in launchSettings.json file configured like below:
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:52171/",
        "sslPort": 44308
    }
}

If you run on Kestrel, Kestrel might be receiving an anonymous request first, which is then redirected to an authenticated request. This can result in the HandleRequirementAsync method being called twice.
Reference:Windows Authentication Runs On Kestrel
